# AJAX form only submitting when unobtrusive AJAX is NOT loaded

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax

I have two identical AJAX forms in my website (the only difference is the way they are included). One form only works when I include unobtrusive AJAX in my template. The other form only works when I DON'T include unobtrusive AJAX. Here's the form that isn't working:

```
@model ViewModels.Book.FindNewBookViewModel
@{
    AjaxOptions options = new AjaxOptions
                              {
                                  HttpMethod = "Get",
                                  UpdateTargetId = "book-overview", 
                                  Url = Url.Action("BooksData", "Book"),
                                  LoadingElementId = "loading", 
                                  LoadingElementDuration = 2000,
                              };
}

@using (Ajax.BeginForm("BooksData", "Book", options, new { @class = "form-search" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="row-fluid">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Search, new { autofocus = "autofocus" })
        <input type="submit" value="Search" class="btn btn-primary btn-small"/>
    </div>

    <div id="loading" class="loading">
        <p>Searching...</p>
    </div>

    <div id="book-overview" class="row-fluid">
        @Html.Action("BooksData", "Book", new { search = Model })
    </div>
}
```

And the controller method that should handle the calls from this form:

```
[Authorize]
public ActionResult BooksData(FindNewBookViewModel viewModel)
{
    if (viewModel.Search == null)
    {
        return PartialView();
    }

    var data = _bookService.FetchBooks(viewModel.Search);

    return data != null ? PartialView(data) : PartialView();
}
```

When I load the form, it performs an empty request to the action method. But when I fill in something and click the submit button, no request is performed.

The only difference between the working and the non-working form is that the working form is included in another page through Html.Action() and the non-working form has its own page that is navigated directly to.

These are my JS libs that I loaded into the _layout:

```
jquery-2.0.0.min.js
jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js
jquery.validate.min.js
jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js
```

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: So the new jquery 2.0 does not have perfectly good Ajax built-in anymore?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating my dependencies resolved the problem. Guess this was not my fault but a bug in the Unobtrusive AJAX library.